# Mathematics/Mechanics Problem

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

I would like to ask you if anybody could help me with this problem.

[image]

So far i know that the positions where B and A have to meet are at distances L and L+2r
[image]

Comment: Can you show what you have done? Also, might be a better question for physics, than math.

Comment: Well i have done not much so far. I put all equations together that i would need.. like an(normal accelaration)=v^2/r ect.

Comment: @user I think tpb261 means: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Velcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

Let $t_1$ be the time taken for particle $A$ moves from $A_0$ to $H$ and let $t_2$ be the time taken for particle $A$ moves from $A_0$ to $K$, then
\begin{align}
d_{1A}&=v_{A0}t_1+\frac12a_At_1^2\\
l&=0+\frac12a_At_1^2\\
t_1&=\sqrt{\frac{2l}{a_A}}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
d_{2A}&=v_{A0}t_2+\frac12a_At_2^2\\
l+2r&=0+\frac12a_At_2^2\\
t_2&=\sqrt{\frac{2l+4r}{a_A}}.
\end{align}
Similarly, for particle $B$ we have
\begin{align}
d_{1B}&=v_{B0}t_1+\frac12at_1^2\\
\frac14\pi r&=v_{B0}t_1+\frac12at_1^2\tag1\\
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
d_{2B}&=v_{B0}t_2+\frac12at_2^2\\
\frac34\pi r&=v_{B0}t_2+\frac12at_2^2.\tag2\\
\end{align}
Now, plug in $t_1$ to $(1)$ and $t_2$ to $(2)$, then solve the equations to obtain $v_{B0}$ and $a$.